# Ionic 4 dynamic photo url isn't working - no image shown

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my app I'm doing this:

```
<ion-col *ngFor ="let place of intentList, let photo of photoList">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-card-content>
          <img class="img" src = "{{photo}}" (click)="clickedImage(place.intent)">
          <div>{{place.val}}</div>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
```

the array photoList contains strings with different photo url. This is the array:

```
this.photoList = ["./assets/images/001-breakfast.png", "./assets/images/002-brunch.png", "./assets/images/003-sandwich.png",
      "./assets/images/004-food.png", "./assets/images/005-dinner.png", "./assets/images/006-cake.png", "./assets/images/007-cocktail.png"]
```

But this is what my app looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ion-col *ngFor ="let place of intentList; let i=index;">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-card-content>
          <img class="img" src = "{{photo[i]}}" (click)="clickedImage(place.intent)">
          <div>{{place.val}}</div>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
```

You can achieve it Using index:

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't run 2 loops in angular. So you are actually not getting the value of photo path in your variable photo.
But instead you are getting the value of variable place in the variable photo.

you can check it printing the value of photo

```
{{photo}}
```